# Liferay SessionMessages & SessionErrors in MVCAction override

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-7

I am using Liferay DXP SP7.  I'm trying to get Liferay's SessionErrors and SessionMessages to add success & error messages to a page containing a custom portlet via an overridden Liferay MVCAction class 
- `com.liferay.dynamic.data.lists.form.web.internal.portlet.action.AddRecordMVCActionCommand`. I'm using the technique explained [here](https://web.liferay.com/web/user.26526/blog/-/blogs/fixing-module-package-access-modifiers) to override this internal class because we need to augment some of the Liferay forms functionality by adding things like the ability to edit a form after it's been submitted. This is working just fine. The issue I am running into is that I can't seem to get Liferay's `SessionMessages` and `SessionErrors` functionality to work. All I want to do is display error or success messages to the user to let them know if a form save worked. My forms are displayed by a custom portlet that retrieves forms via ajax call to Liferay's DDLFormPortlet (which actually calls my custom `AddRecordMVCActionCommand`).  In the custom `AddRecordMVCActionCommand` I add success or error messages using `SessionMessages.add(actionRequest, "formSaveSuccess");` or `SessionErrors.add(actionRequest, "formSaveError");`.  I have my Language.properties file in src/main/resources/content with the follownig content:

```
form-save-success=Report saved successfully.
form-save-error=An unexpected error occurred while trying to save the report, please try again.
```

My JSP page has the following required imports & tags:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/ui" prefix="liferay-ui" %>
<%@ include file="/init.jsp" %>
<liferay-ui:success key="formSaveSuccess" message="form-save-success" />
<liferay-ui:error key="formSaveError" message="form-save-error" />
```

I have followed the instructions found in Liferay's documentation [here](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/displaying-messages-and-errors) to add my languages keys, set up the JSP & add the messages to the session in my MVCAction class. I have read and re-read these instructions several times and everything appears to be set up correctly.  I get no error messages in the log, yet my success & error messages never show up.  Any help that someone could provide would be very helpful.

Comment: That is odd, this is normally a pretty straightforward feature. it must be some small detail. did you remembered "javax.portlet.resource-bundle=content.Language"

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]? I'm seconding Victor on the "normally pretty straightforward" - even without proper language configuration you should at least see the translation key

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys. I think the issue is that even though my `AddRecordMVCActionCommandOverride` is in the same module as my portlet, it's overriding DDLFormsPortlet stuff so it's putting my messages in the DDLFormsPortlet's session.  I was able to verify this by putting the form on the Liferay forms portlet and my messages show up there. So, is there any easy way to use Liferay's success/error messages cross-portlet? I have private session set to false on my portlet and that's how DDLFormsPortlet is when I look at the source but apparently I need more than that.